# Username/password signin and signup are still available, but should be disabled

Tags: azure-api-management

I have deleted the username and password default identity provider from my APIM instance and also disabled the signup. Instead I have configured Azure AD as identity provider. Despite this the developer portal makes it possible to sign in both with username/password and azure ad, and it's possible to sign up.

Overview page: [image]

Identities page: [image]

Setting: [image]

Signup settings: [image]

Answer (score 1):

According to some test in my side, it seems the username/password sign in will not be removed even if delete "Username and password" in "**Identities**" tab. But you can delete the widget directly, do it like below screenshot show:
[image]

You can also delete the widget "**For your password**".

Then click "Save changes" and click "Publish website".
[image]
[image]

After that, close the developer portal window and re-open it again, and copy the url to another inprivate window. Click "sign in", the page will not show username/password sign in box.
[image]

Comment: This is actually what I’ve done to get rid of sign up, thus I upvoted your answer.